# Getting a value error from converting python list into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I'm working with a piece of code written by someone else for domain generalization, and as part of it, I have a dataloader set up for loading my training, validation, and test data for one of my datasets. The code works fine when I load in the train or test data but when I try and load in the val data, I get **Value Error: could not broadcast input array from shape (320,371) into shape (320)** in the load_samples function at the images=np.asarray(images) line. I understand what this error is saying but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's saying it. The code for the val section is identical to the ones for the train and test sections and the csv file I'm reading from is the exact same format as the other two csv files. I'm also calling the get_chexpert function for each of them the exact same way. Additionally, the dataloader for my other dataset has nearly identical code to this one and can create the validation set just fine. I tried testing if it was the csv file by replacing the val csv with the test csv but I still get the same error. Can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong? I feel like it must be some stupidly obvious mistake but I just can't see it.

```
import os
import csv
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.utils.data as data
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

import params


class Chexpert(data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, root, train=True, val=False, transform=None):
        """Init chexpert dataset."""
        # init params
        self.root = os.path.expanduser(root)
        self.train = train
        self.val = val
        self.transform = transform
        self.dataset_size = None


        self.train_data, self.train_labels = self.load_samples()
        if self.train:
            total_num_samples = self.train_labels.shape[0]
            indices = np.arange(total_num_samples)
            np.random.shuffle(indices)
            self.train_data = self.train_data[indices[0:self.dataset_size]]
            self.train_labels = self.train_labels[indices[0:self.dataset_size]]


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Get images and target for data loader.

        Args:
            index (int): Index
        Returns:
            tuple: (image, target) where target is index of the target class.
        """
        img, label = self.train_data[index], self.train_labels[index]
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)
        label = torch.LongTensor([np.int64(label).item()])
        return img, label

    def __len__(self):
        """Return size of dataset."""
        return self.dataset_size

    def load_samples(self):
        """Load sample images from dataset."""
        # some arbitrary limits so I'm not loading 100,000 images while debugging
        numtr = 50
        numts = 20
        numvl = 10
        data_root = os.path.join(self.root, 'CheXpert-v1.0-small')
        images = []
        labels = []
        if self.val:
            val_info = csv.reader(open(os.path.join(data_root, 'effusion-val-split.csv'), 'r'))
            for count, row in enumerate(val_info):
                if count == numvl:
                    break
                image = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(self.root, row[0])))
                images.append(image)
                labels.append(row[1])
        elif self.train:
            train_info = csv.reader(open(os.path.join(data_root, 'effusion-train-split.csv'), 'r'))
            for count, row in enumerate(train_info):
                if count == numtr:
                    break
                image = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(self.root, row[0])))
                images.append(image)
                labels.append(row[1])
        elif not self.val and not self.train:
            test_info = csv.reader(open(os.path.join(data_root, 'effusion-test-split.csv'), 'r'))
            for count, row in enumerate(test_info):
                if count == numts:
                    break
                image = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(self.root, row[0])))
                images.append(image)
                labels.append(row[1])
        images = np.asarray(images)
        labels = np.asarray(labels)
        self.dataset_size = labels.shape[0]
        return images, labels


def get_chexpert(train, val):
    """Get chexpert dataset loader."""
    # image pre-processing
    pre_process = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(),
                                      transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
                                      transforms.ToTensor(),
                                      #transforms.Normalize(
                                          #mean=params.dataset_mean,
                                          #std=params.dataset_std)])
    ])

    # dataset and data loader
    chexpert_dataset = Chexpert(root=params.data_root,
                        train=train,
                        val=val,
                        transform=pre_process)

    chexpert_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset=chexpert_dataset,
        batch_size=params.batch_size,
        shuffle=True)

    return chexpert_data_loader
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load dataset
    print("Loading Source Train Data")
    src_data_loader = get_chexpert()

    print("Loading Source Validation Data")
    src_data_loader_val = get_chexpert(train=False, val=True)

    print("Loading Source Test Data")
    src_data_loader_eval = get_chexpert(train=False)

    print("Loading Target Train Data")
    tgt_data_loader = get_nih()

    print("Loading Target Validation Data")
    tgt_data_loader_val = get_nih(train=False, val=True)

    print("Loading Target Test Data")
    tgt_data_loader_eval = get_nih(train=False)
```

Comment: I suspect `images` is a list of arrays that differ in shape.  It can't make a 3d array.  Sometimes it falls back on making a 1d object array.  Sometimes it fails with an error like this.

Comment: That must be it. The images in my other dataset are all 1024x1024 but in this dataset there are a few variable sizes. Most are 390x390 but a few have different heights around 390. Still, that's also true for the train and test sets as well. Why would this set fail and the others still work? In any case, I'll try resizing the images to a standard size before adding them to the array.